# Toggle multiple divs with one

Tags: jquery, html

When I click `<div class="col-md-12 lightgray h70 toggle">` the three divs below should toggle, but it doesn't work.

**jQuery**

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
  $(this).find('.expander-child').slideToggle(500);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-12 lightgray h70 toggle">    
   <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">Document Name</span3>
   <span3 class="floatright"><i class="arr-up"></i></span3>    
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 lightergray h70 bottomBorder subDiv">
   <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">Document Name</span3>
   <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">20 October 2016</span3>
   <span3 class="floatright"><a href="#"><label class="dlButton">Download</label></a></span3>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 lightergray h70 bottomBorder subDiv">
   <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">Document Name</span3>
   <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">20 October 2016</span3>
   <span3 class="floatright"><a href="#"><label class="dlButton">Download</label></a></span3>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ux2mjx4r/)

Comment: You want to slide elements with the "expander-child" class, but as far as I can see, you have no elements with that class.

Comment: Please re-read your question and fix the mess of spelling and grammar

Comment: Please show the code in which you use "expander-child" class on div elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this solution is exactly what do you expect, because I just basically added a new class for all elements to be hidden. Then, used jquery to toggle it.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $('.x').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  /*
  or
  display: none;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 lightgray h70 toggle">

  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">Document Name</span3>
  <span3 class="floatright"><i class="arr-up"></i>
  </span3>

</div>

<div class="x col-md-12 lightergray h70 bottomBorder">
  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">Document Name</span3>
  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">20 October 2016</span3>
  <span3 class="floatright">
    <a href="#">
      <label class="dlButton">Download</label>
    </a>
  </span3>
</div>

<div class="x col-md-12 lightergray h70 bottomBorder">
  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">Document Name</span3>
  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">20 October 2016</span3>
  <span3 class="floatright">
    <a href="#">
      <label class="dlButton">Download</label>
    </a>
  </span3>
</div>

<div class="x col-md-12 lightergray h70 bottomBorder">
  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">Document Name</span3>
  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">20 October 2016</span3>
  <span3 class="floatright">
    <a href="#">
      <label class="dlButton">Download</label>
    </a>
  </span3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The divs are not inside `<div class="toggle">`, so `find()` is not necessary. With class `subdiv` it works. Don't forget to include jQuery in `<head>`.

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $(".subDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 lightgray h70 toggle">

  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">Document Name</span3>
  <span3 class="floatright"><i class="arr-up"></i>
  </span3>

</div>

<div class="col-md-12 lightergray h70 bottomBorder subDiv">
  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">Document Name</span3>
  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">20 October 2016</span3>
  <span3 class="floatright">
    <a href="#">
      <label class="dlButton">Download</label>
    </a>
  </span3>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 lightergray h70 bottomBorder subDiv">
  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">Document Name</span3>
  <span3 class="font16 menuSeparate">20 October 2016</span3>
  <span3 class="floatright">
    <a href="#">
      <label class="dlButton">Download</label>
    </a>
  </span3>
</div>
```